# Does Firebase Custom event with Parameters requires extra time/setup to show in Debug View

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

when i call this function, the debug.log appears properly, but the firebase event don't shows at all in the DebugView

```
public void fb_GameFail(int id)
    {
        Debug.Log("FIREBASE EVENT: LEVEL FAILED @Lvl " + (id + 1));
        FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_fail:", "failID", (id + 1));
        //FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("dead_player");
    }
```

however, if i comment the "level_fail" event, and enable the "dead_player" event (one with parameter and the other without), the "dead_player" event appears correctly and in real time in the DebugView.

Am i missing something here ? does the events with custom take more times to appear ?

What i don't understand is that i do have another event with parameter and it shows up properly:

[image]

and its code is exactly the same as the "level_fail" event:

```
 public void fb_LevelUp(int id)
    {
        Debug.Log("FIREBASE EVENT: LEVEL COMPLETE @Lvl " + (id + 1));
        FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_up", "ID", id + 1);

    }
```

but this has been the main issue since i started using firebase, "level_up" event was showing perfectly since day one, while the "level_fail" doesn't, the only remark that i can add is that initially both of these events had the same parameter name, they were both using a text named "ID"

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_up", "ID", id + 1);
 FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_fail", "ID", id + 1);
```

but i highly doubt that would be the issue.

PS:

I remember clicking on the "3 dots" in front of the "Level_up" event to enable the parameter tracking, the problem is "level_fail" event **never** showed up.

Also in case its not clear, am using Firebase with Unity (2018.1.0f2).

Thanks!

EDIT:

forgot to say that i also tried spamming a test Event with a parameter, and it worked too:
[image]

but when doing the same thing but with the "levelFail" event nothing shows up :

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            //  FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("testingEVENT", "testID", Random.Range(0, 10));
            fb_GameFail(GameManager._gameManager._currentLevel);
        }
    }
```

knowing that logcat is showing that the method is being called properly:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
public void fb_GameFail(int id)
{
    Debug.Log("FIREBASE EVENT: LEVEL FAILED @Lvl " + (id + 1));
    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_fail:", "failID", (id + 1));
    //FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("dead_player");
}
```

I can see that you used a semicolon in the event name for "level_fail". As far as I know, the custom event names can only have letters, numbers, and underscores in them. Perhaps that is what is causing the issue?

**UPDATE**: Thanks @Pux0r3 for providing the relevant link to the documentation:  [firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/event-names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/event-names)

Comment: This is accurate: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/event-names

"Event names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character. The "firebase_", "google_", and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used."